# Building Django app using Comet/Orbited on Apache, use mod_wsgi or mod_python?

Tags: python, django, apache, comet

Building a Django app on a VPS. I am not very experienced with setting up my own server, but I decided to try a VPS this time around.

I have been doing a bunch of research to learn how to "properly" setup a LAMPython server using the Apache worker MPM. Naturally, the mod_python vs mod_wsgi debate came up.

Reading Graham Dumpleton's blog and his various mailinglist responses, I've learned quite a bit. Particularly, that the performance of mod_python could be greatly improved by using worker MPM - as described at [Load spikes and excessive memory usage in mod_python](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/load-spikes-and-excessive-memory-usage.html)

Regardless, I had decided to go with mod_wsgi(daemon mode) + worker MPM, but then I started looking into implementing Comet and I got a bit confused.

I was considering implementing comet using the technique described by Dark Porter ( http://darkporter.com/?p=7) because it looks like it optimizes the django setup a bit more by having it all in one process, but he specifically says that he uses mod_python and makes no mention of mod_wsgi.

So my questions:

1) Is it possible to implement Dark Porter's method using mod_wsgi?

2) If you were setting a server to support Django+Comet, what components would you use and why? (mod_python vs mod_wsgi / DarkPortersMethod vs MorbidQ vs RabbitMQ)

Thanks

Comment: The post you refer to has been moved, I found it here: http://www.royalbarrel.com/blog_files/4.django_orbited.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, absolutely.
2. I would probably use Orbited as implemented by Dark Porter - It's the simplest solution to get your code running, and implemented in pure python. Not to mention, based on Twisted and thus *very* scalable, and has a well-established community of Django users.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. The confidence in your response to #1 is reassuring.

Comment: Awesome, if you have any trouble, let me know. I just completed a server a lot like the one you're planning, and went through several implementations. Since you're on a VPS, remember you're not limited to just Apache front ends.